# Alias a memory database with sqlite in php

Tags: php, unit-testing, sqlite

So my company has been pushing an effort to do more unit testing, which I think is good. However, our product is fairly database heavy, and some purists part of the team to set the standards (that I am on) are insistent on "no mysql database EVER in a unit test"

While normally this would be fine if starting off from this point, we have a ton of old code that you're very rarely going to not use even a piece of during a unit test. Doing some research, some people suggest using an sqlite in memory database to handle working in a situation like this, where you may have methods that need to take a piece of data from the db, and then do some complex logic on that data.

Essentially I have it working if the database isn't specified in the query, however if it is it will not work, because i can't find a way to alias the memory database. Is it possible? Essentially I want to be able to run a query like "SELECT * FROM config.users WHERE id='2'" on a memory database

Comment: The syntaxes of MySQL and sqlite are a bit different. You might run into problems if you try to run your MySQL queries in sqlite.

Comment: I understand that, I just don't want things to break from a simple lookup from the config table. Complex queries may break, but what I'm looking for is a solution that at least can pull easy data without having to re-write all of our code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were in your shoes, I think I'd first try to use MySQL's own [in-memory database engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html). I think this would require rewriting the least amount of code.

Since you're using php, you might be able to rewrite to use dependency injection and mock objects. [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) is a popular mock object framework for php; there are others.

Comment: I agree with you, but the logic of this "group" is really odd, and no matter how much I voice my opinion they seem to disagree, so I was more so looking for the easiest "non-mysql" solution. How I would do it is set the tables in mysql, and then just throw away all write queries (and you can test against the actual write query string for the unit test if you really wanted)

I looked into mockery, and have been considering it, just trying to research all options to be able to present at the moment

Comment: Well, there are a couple of ways to look at that kind of problem. If the group is going to allow any in-memory database for development and testing, you can make a *good* case for using the MySQL memory engine. If the group *isn't* going to allow such a thing, then mocking is a sensible way to go. (You'd probably have to rewrite *some* code.)